# innerHTML Adding Duplicates When Looping Through Increasing Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm sorry if the title makes no sense. I am attempting to make a text input add strings to an array, which I then want to turn into a visual list. However, when using innerHTML to put the strings into a div, it prints the entire array rather than only the new string being added. Here is my code:

```
var nameList = [];

    function addToList(frm) {
        var list = document.getElementById("list");

        if(frm.name.value !== "") {
            nameList.push(frm.name.value);
        } else {
            alert("Not a name.");
        };

        for(var i=0, len=nameList.length; i<len; i++) {
            list.innerHTML += "<div>"+nameList[i]+"</div>";
        };
    }
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle for your problem?

Comment: You are looping over the entire array every time you add a new item. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sure. http://jsfiddle.net/Caterpiggle/3qyyht5j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can forgo your entire for loop. Everytime you've pushed a name, just add that name to the innerHTML. There is no need to iterate through your entire list everytime.

```
var nameList = [];

function addToList(frm) {
    var list = document.getElementById("list");

    if(frm.name.value !== "") {
        nameList.push(frm.name.value);
        list.innerHTML += "<div>"+frm.name.value+"</div>";
    } else {
        alert("Not a name.");
    };
}
```

Note: I'm keeping your array assuming that it's used elsewhere outside of the provided snippet.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to get the data from the array, not the text input.

Comment: They both accomplish the same thing really, but if you're pedantic about it you can replace that line with:
`list.innerHTML += "<div>"+nameList[nameList.length-1]+"</div>";`

Answer (score 0):

You're starting at the 0 array index each time you call the function, so it iterates the entire array every time it's called. If you want to only output the newest value when it's added, forget the loop and output `frm.name.value` each time the function is called.

Comment: I understand that I could simply skip the loop and get the values directly from the input, and I tried that first. However, when manipulating the data I started running into issues since the display and the array would be separate.

Comment: In that case, maybe have a separate function outside of the first one that is called when all the data has been added. The second function would contain the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're merely appending the new item to both the array and the HTML when the function is called, you don't need to loop through all items in the array and append them to the HTML; you can just add `"<div"+frm.name.value+"</div>"` to the HTML.

You'll only need to loop through all the array elements if there's a chance one of them has changed since the last time the function was called.

On an unrelated note, when you're just appending HTML to an element, you'll see a major performance improvement if you use `element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",yourHTML);` instead of `element.innerHTML += yourHTML;`. Check out the [jsperf test here](http://jsperf.com/thrig-appending-html) to see for yourself!

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not so clear.

I think what you are trying to do is to have the values that have been input so far in an array and at the same time you want to show them on the screen right?

```
for(var i=0, len=nameList.length; i<len; i++) {
            list.innerHTML += "<div>"+nameList[i]+"</div>";
        };
```

The above code that you are running is not right. `+=` is not valid here as it will add whetever html you have already rendered, which is not right.

```
list.innerHTML = "<div>"+nameList[i]+"</div>";
```

If you want to do in this way.